# How to change the icon for android application created in Google App Inventor?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-listview, android-emulator

I am creating an android application in Google app inventor. Every time an application is created the app inventor itself creates a default icon. I don’t know how to change this icon.

Can anybody tell me how to change the icon for an android app created in Google App Inventor?

Answer (score 9):

[image]

You can get more information here : http://www.appinventor.org/appPage

Answer (score 3):

Select your project and look to the right side of the screen, to the properties column. There you have "Icon" box. So just click that box, select "Upload new..." and choose your icon at the disk.